# How to merge multiple 2d arrays with different lenghts in one big array to display it in google spreadsheets?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, jagged-arrays

I am working with different 2d arrays (rows and columns, google app script). For instance (r = row, c = column):

```
var array1 = 
[[r1c1, r1c2, r1c3], 
 [r2c1, r2,c2, r2c2]]

var array2 = 
[[r1c4, r1c5], 
[r2c4, r2c5], 
[r3c4, r3c5]]
```

and I want to have it like that:

```
var array1and2 = 
[[r1c1, r1c2, r1c3, r1c4, r1c5], 
 [r2c1, r2c2, r2c3, r2c4, r2c5], 
 [empty, empty, empty, r3c4, r4c5]
]
```

It doesn't have to be empty but as already said I want to display it in google spreadsheets. The second array should be in the first empty row and column next to the first array. 
I hope it is understandable and thank you very much for you help!

Comment: How about this: `array2.map((elem, i)=>[...(array1[i] || new Array(array1[0].length).fill('empty')), ...elem])`

Answer (score 5):

Somethink like this you can do:

```js
var array2 = [['r1c4', 'r1c5'],
['r2c4', 'r2c5'],
['r3c4', 'r3c5']];

var array1 = [['r1c1', 'r1c2', 'r1c3'],
['r2c1', 'r2,c2', 'r2c2']];

var result = array2.map((elem, i)=>[...(array1[i] || new Array(array1[0].length).fill('empty')), ...elem]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading your question as being about not just how to create an amalgamated array but actually to manipulate the data in situ, so I'd approach it something like this (assuming that array 1 lives on sheet1 and array 2 lives on sheet2:

```
function translateArray(){
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = sh.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var os = sh.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
var range1 = ss.getRange("A1:C2");//2 rows 3 columns
var range1Width = range1.getValues()[0].length;//checks length of first row - the width
var range2 = os.getRange("A1:B3");//3 rows 2 columns
var data = range2.getValues();

ss.getRange(1,range1Width,data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

}
```

This code copies the data in sheet2 to sheet 1 alongside it.

use [1] instead of [0] in range1Width if you have header data wider than the real data.

Answer (score 0):

A less orthodox approach:

```
function merge2Arrays() {
  var array1 = [['r1c1', 'r1c2', 'r1c3'],['r2c1', 'r2,c2', 'r2c3']];
  var array2 = [['r1c4', 'r1c5'],['r2c4', 'r2c5'],['r3c4', 'r3c5']];
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.insertSheet('xxxxx');
  sh.getRange(1,1,array1.length,array1[0].length).setValues(array1);
  sh.getRange(1,array1[0].length+1,array2.length,array2[0].length).setValues(array2);
  const a=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  ss.deleteSheet(sh);
  ret a;
}

function merge3Arrays() {
  var array1 = [['r1c1', 'r1c2', 'r1c3'],['r2c1', 'r2,c2', 'r2c3']];
  var array2 = [['r1c4', 'r1c5'],['r2c4', 'r2c5'],['r3c4', 'r3c5']];
  var array3 = [["r1C6"],["r2c6"],["r3c6"],["r4c6"],["r5c6"],["r6c6"]];
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.insertSheet('xxxxx');
  sh.getRange(1,1,array1.length,array1[0].length).setValues(array1);
  sh.getRange(1,array1[0].length+1,array2.length,array2[0].length).setValues(array2);
  sh.getRange(1,array1[0].length + array2[0].length + 1,array3.length,array3[0].length).setValues(array3);
  const a=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  ss.deleteSheet(sh);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(JSON.stringify(a)), "Display Array");
}
```